# Use shell command to set env variable in Dockerfile

Tags: shell, docker, environment-variables

I am trying ot set up a custom redis alpine image and I would like to set the private IP that get assigned to the instance as an environment variable. In order to do so, I am using the following command:

> PRIVATE_IP=$("ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p'")

Unfortunately, when I try to do the same in the Dockerfile, it interprets it as a string and as an output I get `ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p'`. Not very useful.

I have trued using a bash script, but the issue with that is that it doesn't permanently set the variable.

Is there any solution to this that you are aware of?

Thank you in advanced,

Ettore

Comment: Why do you quote the command in the command substitution?